# Adding new line in excel cell generated via html

Tags: php, html, excel, newline

I'm trying to generate an excel file using html  in php and responding with an excel Content-type. Everything works fine except new lines within a cell  . They are not preserved.
I've tried **&#13 ;&#10 ; \r\n ,chr(13).chr(10)** and it didn't work.
I'm trying to get the same result from **alt + enter** from microsoft Excel .

I am generating in a cell content like:

```
 http:\\www.example.com\blah
 (Link)
 http:\\www.example.com\blah2
 (Event) ...
```

these have to be in a single cell  and also converting the link text to hyperlinks would be great :).

Comment: Have you tried using only chr(10)?

Comment: I've tried almost all combinations .. The closest to the solution i got is </br>-ing and  set the collspan of the neighboring cells to nr_of br + 1

Comment: If you're generating HTML, then it's not Excel, it's just Excel being nice and reading it as a spreadsheet for you. For far greater control over content and formatting, you should probably investigate using something PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) which generates real Excel xls/xlsx files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found a solution here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1095-maintaining-line-breaks-in-an-html-excel-file.htm

> The solution I found is to add into a
>   stylesheet:
>
> ```
> br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
> ```

Comment: Obscure, but awesome this was the first google link to solve my problem.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thank you for for noticing. I found a different link explaining the same thing. I think this one will stay for quite a long time.